# how to write SWRL rules in protégé 5?

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I have to write some rules to my ontology. I opened the rules window to write my rules. 
The problem that every time I write a rule I get an exception from protege

```
OWLRuntimeException: org.protege.editor.owl.model.classexpression.OWLExpressionParserException: Encountered Rule at line 1 column 1. Expected one of:
Rule:
```

I event installed an ontology(with rules) from the Internet and I was able to reason on it using OWLapi and Pellet  but if I open it from protege and try to 
update a rule(I don't change anything I just click edit and then ok) I also get the same error . 
I made some search and I know that it's a bug but maybe someone has a good solution .
Any one knows how to solve this issue? 
[image: The error that I am getting in protege]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and found a solution in the Protege User Mailing List. This is the thread http://protege-project.136.n4.nabble.com/The-rule-editor-in-Protege-5-doesn-t-work-td4661832.html

At the end there is a link to a beta-16 snapshot, which I installed on my system. In this Version of Protege 5 it is possible to write and use SWRL- rules.

Hope this helps. 
Best regards,
Sabina